# How to make an axios request call every so minutes?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Here is my doubt: I use a `Vue` and `Laravel` application and I'm trying to make a function that makes a call for the server every 5 minutes (for example) to refresh the logs on a page.

The only way I've found is using the `JavaScript` native function `setInterval`.

Is that really the best and only way? I just wanna know if there is a different approach to this kind of scenario.

Comment: Does my answer clear your doubts or do you still need help with your question?

Comment: thanks, ive just implemented it and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general native functions are usually the best choice.

For this scenario, you could indeed use `interval`:

```
let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
  //make call to refresh logs
  console.log('interval')
}, 1000); //using 1s for demo purposes
```

The alternative would be to use `timeout`:

```
let myTimeout = (() => {
  //make call to refresh logs
  console.log('timeout')
  //you could put this timeout inside successful log refresh
  setTimeout(() => { 
    myTimeout()
  }, 1000);
})
```

Please have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/crtzjmh8/). Hope it gives you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be better if you will use `setTimeout` after every each successful request. What are you trying to implement is known as Long Polling.

There is [some examples](https://gist.github.com/ngugijames/c3eaf929f3512def986b).